# Dynamically Creating Radio Button Groups in OAF

Tags: oracle, frameworks

My use case is:

Create a questionnaire page with Yes/No questions. The questions will be fnd messages from the database and there can be multiple set of questions. I should be able to display radio buttons for each question with Yes/No question. The rows and radio button groups I need to create programmatically.

I am using Oracle Application Framework (OAF) with JDev 10.1.3.3.0